# Java - GridBagLayout wrong ratio

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I am new to creating a GUI with Java. I tried to use the GridBagLayout for a project but i am stuck here.

I want to make the Button and the two JLabels the same size but the button is bigger.

```
public class Menu extends JPanel {
    
    public Menu() {
        
        
        
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        
        
        GridBagLayout gb = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(gb);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        
        
        JButton b1 = new JButton();
        b1.setText("Start");
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty= 1;
        gb.setConstraints(b1, gbc);
        add(b1);
        
        
        JPanel Gap = new JPanel();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty= 1;
        
        gb.setConstraints(Gap, gbc);
        add(Gap);
        
        
        RadioPanel radio = new RadioPanel();
        
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        
        gb.setConstraints(radio, gbc);
        add(radio);
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }

}
```

[Click here to see my GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOGYr.png)

This is my code and this is what it looks like.

Comment: If the components in the grid should be the same size, then don't use a GridBagLayout. Use a GridLayout instead. It is a lot simpler to use.

Comment: The weights specify how *additional space* is distributed. So with equal weights, if the button’s preferred size is bigger than the other component’s preferred sizes, the button will always be bigger by that amount. As @HovercraftFullOfEels said, making three components the same size is much easier to achieve with `GridLayout`.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it by setting the preferred size of the button to (1,1). I guess this is not the nicest way but it works.

Comment: (1-)  *I solved it by setting the preferred size* - you should NOT be setting the preferred size. Each Swing component is responsible for determining its preferred size.  *I guess this is not the nicest way but it works.* - actually it doesn't work because the preferred size of each component is different, so the GridBagLayout will also resize each component differently. You were given the simple solution to the problem. Why would you ignore that suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

## `GridLayout`, not `GridBagLayout`

For three equally sized widgets, use [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html) rather than `GridBagLayout`. See Oracle tutorial, [*How to Use GridLayout*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

Here is an example of a button with two labels, all the same size.

```java
package work.basil.example.swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

// An abbreviated version of example code provided by Oracle from:
// https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java
public class ThreeWidgets
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI ( )
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated( true );

        // Establish the window, represented by a `JFrame` object.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Three Widgets App" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        makeContent( frame.getContentPane() );

        // Show window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    private static void makeContent ( Container container )
    {
        container.setLayout( new GridLayout() );

        JButton widget1 = new JButton( "Widget 1" );

        JLabel widget2 = new JLabel( "Widget 2" );
        widget2.setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Color.GREEN ) );

        JLabel widget3 = new JLabel( "Widget 3 with long title" );
        widget3.setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Color.MAGENTA ) );

        container.add( widget1 );
        container.add( widget2 );
        container.add( widget3 );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        // Assign a task to event-dispatching thread: Create and show our GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( ThreeWidgets :: createAndShowGUI );
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of window with GridLayout]